# Ansible ssh public keys copying

Tags: ssh, ansible

I want to create new user and then copy SSH key to this users dir (I've got this key before executing role). After that I'd like to disable password login.

Here's what I've got for now:
My tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Add users
  user: name={{ item }}
        groups=users,wheel
        update_password=on_create
        password=$6$QoFz/cLhsroToP$4...
    with_items:"{{ list }}"

- name: Copy SSH keys
  authorized_key: user={{ item }} key={{ item }}.pub state=present
with_items: "{{ list }}"
```

My vars/main.yml file:

```
list:
    - 'user1'
    - 'user2'
    - 'user3'
```

And here's my question - where are my keys stored? Is that form of copying  correct?

I've got an error:

```
failed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=user1) => {"failed": true, "item": "user1"}
msg: invalid key specified: user1.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

The second task will fail as `authorized_key` expects the `key` parameter to be a string ( [authorized_key docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html#options) ). You can still use the `list` parameter to get the content of the key file, but you will have to use a `lookup`. 
So this is what the second task might look like:

```
- name: "Copy SSH Keys"
  authorized_key: user={{ item }} key={{ lookup('file', item) }} state=present
```

To answer your question "Where would the file be stored, that's entirely up to you. By default ( If you don't specify a path ) the module will look into all the `files/` directories available. So if it's a role it will look into:

`/roles/your_role/files`

`/files`

`./files`

[Lookups docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#intro-to-lookups-getting-file-contents)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, i could'nt comment your post, beacuse my answer would be too long.

I can finally see keys from ansible side, but the task still fails. Here's the output:

```
failed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=user1) => {"failed": true, "item": "user1"}
msg: this module requires key=value arguments (['user=user1', 'key=ssh-rsa', 'AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAA...', 'user@domain', 'state=present'])
```

Am I doing something wrong?

FOUND THE ANSWER!
Quoting the key inputs solves the problem, so the function in my case should look like this:

```
- name: "Copy SSH Keys"
  authorized_key: user="{{ item }}" key="{{ lookup('file', item) }}" state=present
```

Hope it will help someone in the future. Thanks a lot for help!